# What library creates simple 2D graphics, and works in both Pythonista and "normal" Python

Tags: python, graphics, pythonista

I want to generate quite simple 2D graphics. What Python library will work in both Pythonista as well as normal python?

I am a fan of Pythonista, but also a fan of writing apps for "normal" Python on a PC, and want my code to work on both.,..

I know that Pythonista directs people to use the Scene module, but that won't work off in Python elsewhere, I'm pretty sure...

Big thanks!

Comment: possible to bump the attention for this question?

Comment: These kinds of ["Recommendation questions"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) are not a great fit for Stack Overflow. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks. Hmm, well, maybe if I phrased it "are there any libraries that work in both" instead of "what library..." then it would clearly come across as a concrete problem rather than a request for recommendations? Because in a way it's not just curiosity for the best one, it's more about locating a single resource so I can proceed...

Comment: Good question. I would think it's still at risk for being considered a ["List question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki) which is generally frowned upon -- Not because the question doesn't have merit or isn't asked well, but because it doesn't fit the traditional Q&A format of the Stack Exchange sites well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using Pyglet, it works well with both Python and Pythonista.

Here is a link to their repository: [Pyglet](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/wiki/Home)